# Angularjs: ng-options add condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this line

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

everything worked fine, but now in answer from server comes an indeterminate value for `item.label`. Sometimes.

Is it possible to add a condition in this line if this field does not exist then apply another? Or it is impossible for `ng-options`? like this:

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label || item.id  for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. You are almost correct just wrap the expression in parenthesis.

`ng-options="item.subItem as (item.label || item.id)  for item in items track by item.id"`

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3Ljwxx9/).